# Can scoreboard triggers be disabled?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The `trigger` scoreboard type is used to allow players, even without cheats, to modify their value of a scoreboard objective. By typing `/scoreboard players enable <playerName> <objective>` this will allow that player, even without cheats, to use `/trigger` to change their scoreboard value. After triggering, that trigger is disabled again until the enable command is typed again.

While there is a command `/scoreboard players enable`, there isn't a `/scoreboard players disable`. In other words, I can't disable a trigger that has previously been enabled, and now I have to hope  that the player doesn't find out and use `/trigger`, or it will break my map.

Can scoreboard triggers be disabled? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly disable scoreboard triggers, but you can instead trick Minecraft into thinking that the player used `/trigger`, using `/execute`.

```
execute as @p trigger myObjective add 0
```

This command will disable the trigger of the nearest player. Because the `/trigger` is being executed by the nearest player, this makes Minecraft think that they used their trigger.